# Show that $2^{n+1}$ is $O(2^n)$

Tags: proof-writing, asymptotics, computer-science

I just started an algorithm design and analysis class and i'm trying to learn how to properly prove things using big O. I was never taught much about big O in my previous CS classes other than the fact that the dominant term is the point of focus. I am trying to learn the proper way to prove things like this but everything I read confuses me even more. I know that:

$2^{n+1} = 2 * 2^n = O(2^n)$

But I don't think this is not enough to prove this. From other examples i've seen, it seems I need to use a constant c to finish this proof. Is this the correct thought process? Are there other ways to prove something like this? What is the most efficient method of doing so?

If someone could help me understand the process, I would be so grateful. I've seen different ways of proving similar problems but i'm not sure which ways are correct.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Are you confused with the definition of Big O notation? If you were clear about it, then this question is most likely going to be trivial, that is why I ask.

Comment: I know very little about big O, especially when it comes to the mathematical portion. The only thing I ever learned was that the dominant term is what we focus on. Other than that, I know almost nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so look at [this page](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/bigOnotation.html) for the definition of Big O.

What does it say? Well, $f(n)$ is said to be $O(g(n))$ if there exist constants $c$ and $k$ such that if $l \geq k$ then $f(l) \leq c \times g(l)$.

In words : $f(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ *if eventually, a constant multiple of $g$ is bigger than or equal to $f$*.

So, why is it that $2^{n+1}$ is $O(2^n)$? Is it true, that eventually, a constant multiple of $2^n$ is always greater than $2^{n+1}$? Well, let's say we multiply $2^n$ by $2$,then it is $2^{n+1}$, which of course, is greater than or equal to $2^{n+1}$!

So with $c=2$ and $k=1$, we have $2 \times 2^n \geq 2^{n+1}$ for all $n \geq 1$. Therefore , $2^{n+1}$ is $O(2^n)$.

If you have not understood , you may ask.

Comment: That was actually a very nice explanation, thank you! I was unsure how to use the constant c but seeing your proof helps me visualize why its important. I guess my only question is, what is k and where is it used? I'm sorry if that is a stupid question. I just don't see "k" used symbolically anywhere in the proof. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Oh, you see, it does not immediately happen that the constant times $g$ should be greater than $f$. The point from where that starts happening, is $k$. In the case above, actually $k=1$, because the fact that $2^{n+1} \geq 2^{n+1}$  starts holding from $n \geq 1$ itself. Now, if you take something like $2^n $ and $n^3$. It is true that $n^3$ is $O(2^n)$, but it immediately does not hold that $n^3 < 2^n$, I think it stats holding after $n \geq 10$, so in this case $k=10$.